Correlation of the median with the sign of an observation
Let $X_j\overset{iid}\sim\mathrm{Unif}(-1,1)$. Let $\hat{X}_n$ be the sample median. What is the value of
$n\mathbb E[\mathrm{sign}(X_1)\hat{X}_n]$
when $n\to\infty$?

I used the suggestion that $\mathbb{E}[\mathrm{sign}(X_1)\hat{X}_n]=\mathbb{E}[\hat{X}_n|X_1>0]$. Using some combinatorics, it is possible to obtain the pdf of $\hat{X}_n|X_1>0$ which is
$$\frac1{2^{n-1}}\binom{n-1}{\frac{n-1}{2}}\left(1-x^2\right)^{\frac{n-1}2-1}\begin{cases}\frac{n-1}2(1+x)&\textrm{if }x<0\\(1-x^2)+\frac{n-1}2(1+x-2x^2)&\textrm{if }x>0\end{cases}$$
Using symmetry, the expected value of this quantity is
$$\frac1{2^{n-1}}\binom{n-1}{\frac{n-1}{2}}\left(\int_0^1(1-x^2)^{\frac{n-1}2}x\mathrm{d}x+(n-1)\int_0^1(1-x^2)^{\frac{n-1}2-1}x^2\mathrm{d}x-(n-1)\int_0^1(1-x^2)^{\frac{n-1}2-1}x^3\mathrm{d}x\right).$$
Thus, the final answer is $$n\mathbb{E}[\mathrm{sign}(X_1)\hat{X}_n]=1-2\frac{n}{n+1}\frac1{2^{n-1}}\binom{n-1}{\frac{n-1}{2}}\approx1-2\sqrt{\frac{2}{n\pi}}.$$

$\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb E}\newcommand{\sign}{\mathrm{sign}}\newcommand{\1}{\mathbf{1}}\newcommand{\P}{\mathbf{P}}$
First lets assume $n=2m+1$. The cfd of $\hat X_n$ given by $\P(\hat X_n \le x)$ equals the probability $\P(\sum_{k=1}^{n} \1_{\{X_k \le x\}} = m+1)$. This can be computed using the binomial distribution. By defining $p(x):= \frac{1+x}{2}$ and difining a binomial variable $B_n(x)\sim\mathrm{binom}(n,p(x))$ we have
$$
\P(\hat X_n \le x) = \P(B(x) = m+1).
$$
Now towards you question. By switching all signs of the $X_j$ we don't change their distribution but we switch the sign of $\hat X_n$. Thus
$$
\E[\hat X_n |X_1>0] = \E[-\hat X_n |X_1<0]
$$
and so we get
$$
\E[\sign(X_1)\hat X_n] = \frac{1}{2}(\E[\hat X_n|X_1>0] - \E[\hat X_n|X_1<0])=\E[\hat X_n | X_1>0].
$$
Now $X_1$ conditioned on $X_1>0$ is uniform distributed on $[0,1]$ and the other variables on $[-1,1]$. Now one has to make one case distinction for $X_1$ and otherwise compute the median as one would in the unconditioned setting.
$$
\P(\hat X_n \le x | X_1>0) = \P(X_1\le x)\P(B_{n-1}(x) = m) + \P(X_1> x)\P(B_{n-1}(x) = m+1).
$$
Using the well known formula for positive random variable $X$ as $\E[X] = \int_0^{\infty} (1-F_X(x))dx$ we can compute the expectation as
$$
\begin{align*}
\E[\hat X_n \sign(X_1)] &= \E[\hat X_n +1|X_1>0] - 1 = \int_0^2(1-\P(\hat X_n\le x-1 | X_1>0))dx -1\\
&= \int_{-1}^1(1-\P(\hat X_n\le x | X_1>0))dx -1.
\end{align*}
$$
At this point this should be straigh forward to compute as the integral is just an integral over a polynomial of $x$.
